# Angular 7 Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular7, angular-service-worker

I am getting the following error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

I used the prompt "ng add @angular/pwa" to add my ngsw-config.json and manifest file.  This prompt also added my "serviceWorker" : true statement and my register with environment to my app.module.ts

After verifying everything was added properly I then ran the command "ng build --prod" that built successfully and the dist shown was made
[dist folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfOxm.png)

Then I ran "ng serve --prod" and I am receiving the errors shown in the image
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i10yl.png)

Line being used in app.module.ts

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

ngsw-configuration:

```
{
  "index": "/",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "icons",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/icons/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Placement of serviceWorker true in angular.json:

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

Comment: Check your network log in chrome. whether the url is called correctly. because u are trying in local also u used `--prod` flag. production environment is used for this flag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have mentioned the root as dist folder, your `service-worker.js` file must be in the dist folder after you run the `ng build` script.

Add `"precache": "sw-precache --verbose --config=sw-precache-config.js"` to your package.json scripts object.

Then run: `ng build --prod --aot`, then `npm run precache`. Now your service-worker.js file would be present in the dist folder.

Since the angular compiler has compiled your app code into js files and stored it in the dist folder, now you must serve your app from the dist folder.

But the default `ng serve` doesn't support it. I suggest you use `http-server`. `npm install http-server -g`. Then `http-server ./dist -o`. This opens up your app on the default browser.

Comment: @AlexMalikov    giving me error --> npm run precache

> projects@0.0.0 precache C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\An7\test-app
> sw-precache --verbose --config=sw-precache-config.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\An7\test-app\sw-precache-config.js'

Comment: You need just npm install --save-dev sw-precache-webpack-plugin or npm install --global sw-precache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185107/discussion-between-alex-malikov-and-p-j).

Answer (score 2):

Set `production` to `false` in your `environment.ts` file, e.g.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular 10, the solution is just simply to run `http-server` rather than `ng-serve` which unfortunately doesn't support service workers.

#### 1. Use NPM to install `http-server`:

`npm install http-server --save-dev`

#### 2. Serve your project using `http-server`

Then (let's assume your project is called my project), run:

```
# cd into the root folder for your angular project
http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/myproject
```

i.e. this assumes that the exports for your project are located in the folder `dist/myproject/` (change if not).

**Note:** the `-c-1` instruction tells HTTPServer to switch off caching - [see docs for details](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

Comment: @Sofia - the compiled version of your project that webpack produces